# Origin of Gauss-Newton method

Tags: mathematics, terminology, gauss

The Gauss-Newton method can be derived from Newton's method, but I am unable to see how Gauss was linked with this method. It seems unlikely that he himself worked on the method, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undoubtedly, Gauss' name is attached to the name of the Gauss-Newton method due to his pioneering role in the development and application of the least-squares method to non-linear least-squared problems. As to whether he actually conceived of and employed the Gauss-Newton method to solve such problems, the paper ["*A Gauss-Newton method for convex composite optimization*”](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01585997) makes that claim in the introduction.

Addendum: After some more searching, I found where Gauss published his variant of Newton's method:  sections 179-180 of his *Theoria motus corporum coelestium in sectionibus conicis solem ambientum* (1809).